# what does $\varnothing$ map to in a measurable function?

Tags: measure-theory

Here is the question: I am trying to prove a proposition from Schervish. Suppose that $(S,\mathcal{A})$ and $(T,\mathcal{C})$ are measurable spaces. $f:S\rightarrow T$ is a function.  If $\mathcal{C}=\{T,\varnothing\}$ then $f$ is measurable.

I wrote: $f^{-1}(\varnothing)=\varnothing$ and because $\mathcal{A}$ is a sigma field it must contain $\varnothing$. $f^{-1}(T)=S$, which is the also contained in the sigma field because it is the compliment of $\varnothing$.

I do not understand how I can know that  $f^{-1}(\varnothing)=\varnothing$. It seems right, but how do I know for certain? What am I missing?

Comment: Use the definition of $f^{-1}(\emptyset)$. This is $f^{-1}(emptyset):=\{x\in X:\ f(x)\in\emptyset\}=\emptyset$. The last equality is because if you take any $x\in X$ then $f(x)\notin\emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was wondering about!

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is measurable iff for all $A \in \mathcal{C}$, $f^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{A}$.  Well $f^{-1}(\varnothing) = \varnothing \in \mathcal{A}$ and $f^{-1} (T) = S \in \mathcal{A}$.  Then you're done.